# Add a word to a .mp3 file

Tags: objective-c, mp3

In my Mac app I need to take a .mp3 file and add a spoken word to it programmatically. The word is custom and is entered by the user.

How can I do it? Which frameworks should I use and are there any custom libraries to do it?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has libraries for editing video (and I assume, audio) in iOS 4. You should look into [AV Media Framework](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/audio-and-video.html).